# magento 1.9 On Oder Page issue

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, error, edit-order

In admin panel on the particular order page (below of page) I have seen this messages mentioned in the screenshot. How can I fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Is this happening for every order or for only a particular order?

Comment: only some orders

Comment: Is there a debug mode setting that is enabled in the modules configuration in the admin?

Comment: i am not getting your point can you brief it, one debug option in  developer mode but this is disabled

Answer (score 2):

This is an Magento Order Notification Box being added by PayU method.

You need to check with vendor of Extension to modify or remove this notification or look into the code your self.

It is not an error but represents a log of payment.